# Can't populate a TableView with Jruby/Jrubyfx

Tags: jruby, fxml, jrubyfx

I'm trying to make a Jruby app with a TableView but I haven't been able to populate the table with data or even find some sample code to do so. Here's the relevant part of my fxml:

```xml
<TableView prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" id="table">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="name">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="address">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="address" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

And here's the relevant ruby code:

```ruby
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :address

  def initialize
    @name = 'foo'
    @address = 'bar'
  end
end

class HelloWorldApp < JRubyFX::Application
  def start(stage)
    with(stage, title: "Hello World!", width: 800, height: 600) do
      fxml HelloWorldController
      @data = observable_array_list
      @data.add Person.new
      stage['#table'].set_items @data
      show
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong or point me to a working sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [contrib/fxmltableview](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx/tree/master/samples/contrib/fxmltableview) sample; I think that is exactly what you want to do. The issue you are running into is the fact that `PropertyValueFactory` is a Java class, and it is trying to access a `Person` which is a JRuby class. By default this won't work as this question shows, but you can easily fix that by calling `Person.become_java!`. However, even if you do that, it won't work as the `PropertyValueFactory` expects getter methods of the form `[javatype] get[PropertyName]()` whereas `attr_accessor` only generates getter methods of the form `[rubytype] [propertyname]()`. To solve this, use `fxml_accessor` instead, which generates the proper methods (but doesn't use `@` vars, those are the raw property instances):

```ruby
class Person
  include JRubyFX # gain access to fxml_accessor
  # must specify type as the concrete `Property` implementation
  fxml_accessor :name, SimpleStringProperty
  fxml_accessor :address, SimpleStringProperty

  def initialize
    # note use of self to call the method Person#name= instead of creating local variable
    self.name = 'foo'
    self.address = 'bar'
    # could also technically use @address.setValue('bar'), but that isn't as rubyish
  end
end

# become_java! is needed whenever you pass JRuby objects to java classes 
# that try to call methods on them, such as this case. If you used your own 
# cellValueFactory, this probably would not be necessary on person, but still
# needed on your CVF
Person.become_java!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll accept it but I've since moved on to node/react for these kinds of things.